# Avoidable if-else

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is a finished Roman to Decimal numeral convertor.

```
Dictionary<char,int> nTrans = new Dictionary<char,int>();
            nTrans.Add('I',1);
            nTrans.Add('V', 5);
            nTrans.Add('X', 10);
            nTrans.Add('L', 50);
            nTrans.Add('C', 100);
            nTrans.Add('D', 500);
            nTrans.Add('M', 1000);

            string rNum = "XV";
            int dNum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < rNum.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < rNum.Length-1)
                {
                    if (nTrans[rNum[i]] < nTrans[rNum[i + 1]])
                    {
                        dNum -= nTrans[rNum[i]];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dNum += nTrans[rNum[i]];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dNum += nTrans[rNum[i]];
                }
            }
```

But I can't figure out how to escape from using this if-else statement:

```
if (i < rNum.Length-1)
{
//Code
}
else
{
dNum += nTrans[rNum[i]];
}
```

Any suggestions how I can avoid using it? The question is only for optimizing and improving my coding skills!

Comment: I wonder if you should ask this on say _Code Review_ SE?

Comment: `dNum = nTrans[rNum[i]] < nTrans[rNum[i + 1]] ? dNum - nTrans[rNum[i]] : dNum + nTrans[rNum[i]];` This is the code inside your if where you are checking if `i` is less than `rNum.Length-1`. It's shorter but readability is lower.

Comment: @Spectarion Though you eliminate an explicit `if`, yours has the excact same source code _cyclomatic complexity_ as the original code.  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC

Comment: @MickyD Hmmm, I never heard of it. So basically, the ternary operator is the same as if-else performance wise. Nice catch. Thank you very much. I'll definitely read more about it.

Comment: @Spectarion Not a problem.  I use nDepend (awesome) but VS can do so via **Analyse.Calculate Code Metrics**.

Comment: @MickyD I'm not an advanced C# developer (started with ASP.net year ago) and I'm wondering, is `nDepend` too much for me because I can see too many things that I don't understand... kinda confused by those screenshots.

Comment: @Spectarion Yes it can be daunting.  For CC you can just use VS as nDepend can be overkill for purchasing it for that alone.  We got it for other reasons like ensuring changes to code won't lead to API breaking changes or reporting on dependencies or strong coupling. :)

Comment: Is there any other **nDepend**like tool that's lightweight version of it? I'm sure I will Google it out but just asking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you process everything between 0 and `rNum.Length - 1` in the loop, and then process the last one outside of it?

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rNum.Length - 1; i++)
{
// do regular stuff
}

if (rNum.Length != 0)
    dNum += nTrans[rNum[rNum.Length - 1]];
```

If this is in a function, you can move the `rNum.Length == 0` check to the top and just return 0 as dNum if it is true. That way you skip all the extra processing.

Comment: Not only is this weeee faster (reduces conditional checks during loop), it also reduces _cyclomatic complexity_. http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC  +1

Answer (score -2):

Case statements can improve readability, or also a command map/dictionary, where each calculation is stored in dictionary/map and looked up directly.

Comment: Yes, but how is that relevant here?